# Only allow certain user input in html form

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to allow only certain data to be inserted into an html form field...
i currently have

```
pattern="[A-za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}"
```

which works great for a reference number starting with RQ and then 6 numbers.

how can i add another pattern to allow 3 letters with 8 numbers after that?
for example INM12345678

so that users can only use RQ123456 or INM12345678

Comment: apologies... figured it out...

`pattern="[A-za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}|[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{8}"`

Comment: answer your own question below

Comment: You probably can simplify that to [A-Za-z]{2,3}[0-9]{6,8}

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov: Then it would also catch `AA12345678`.

Comment: @Robin Of course, you right

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov is there a way that i can specify that ONLY RQ and INM letters with the 6 and 8 numbers should be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
/(RQ\d{6}|INM\d{8})/
```

here is the demo [see here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Ab)

Comment: could you possibly show me how i could use this for a desktop or laptop's serial number? This number usually range between 5-10 character of which is a mix of a-z A-Z and numbers

Comment: pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{5,10}"

Comment: try this regex this will match alphanumeric characters with range 5-10  /([[:alnum:]]{5,10})/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit valid data as said in comment:

```
^RQ[0-9]{6}|INM[0-9]{8}$
```